# Web Form Routing - Cannot create an abstract class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-routing

Net 3.5 SP1 and attempting to implement a sample copy of http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/11/using-routing-with-webforms.aspx into a sample web application however I seem to be having some issues.

I am running windows vista, IIS 7.0, integrated-mode.

Below is the YSOD:

> Cannot create an abstract class.
>
> **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.MissingMethodException: Cannot create an abstract class.
>
> **Source Error:** An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> **Stack Trace:** [MissingMethodException: Cannot create an abstract class.]
>      System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>      System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache) +86
>      System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache) +230
>      System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +67
>      System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) +1051
>      System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) +111
>      System.Web.Configuration.HandlerFactoryCache..ctor(String type) +57
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.GetFactory(String type) +78
>      System.Web.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +229
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

I have an interface which looks like so:

```
public interface IRoutablePage : IHttpHandler
{
    UrlHelper Url { get; }
    HtmlHelper Html { get; }
    RequestContext RequestContext { get; set;}
}
```

I have an abstract class (RoutablePage) which inherits this interface and System.Web.UI.Page.

I then have a web page (attached to a masterpage) which inherits the RoutablePage class.

I have routes setup in my web config and when I try and access http://local.url/pageName I experience the YSOD with the information above.

Can anyone help solve this issue please?

Cheers

Comment: I think we need to see your web.config section first and then possibly the classes

Comment: If you download the sample project from haacked the web.config is identical.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I was able to find an answer on this forum http://forums.asp.net/t/1272109.aspx

Cross posting what helped me:

> In Web.config -> system.webserver ->
>   handlers, replace

```
  <add name="UrlRoutingHandler"
 preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*"
 path="UrlRouting.axd"
 type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingHandler,
 System.Web.Routing, Version=0.0.0.0,
 Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

> With:

```
  <add name="UrlRoutingHandler"
 preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*"
 path="UrlRouting.axd"
 type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler,
 System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0,
 Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been temporarily fixed. Running the website under IIS7 causes the above problem and running the website using cassini, every runs as expected with no errors.

Any further information on this problem would be appreciated however.